# Move some markdown data from one markdown file to different <div> parts in html via my template

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, middleman, redcarpet

how to parsing markdown to cut off or move some chunks of code from *.md to html with my html template?

I have markdown file like this:
carrot_soup.md

```
Very nice carrot soup
============

I'd like soup like this:

### Ingredients ###

      * carrots
      * celery
      * lentils

### Coocking ###

Boil some water. And eat it with all Ingredients
```

I need to parse it to something like this:

```
<div class="head"">
<h1>Very nice carrot soup</h1>
<p>I'd like soup like this:</p>
</div>
<!-- Something else -->

<div class="Ingredients">
<ul>
<li>carrots</li>
<li>celery</li>
<li>lentils</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="Coocking">
<p>Boil some water. And eat it with all Ingredients</p>
</div>
```

I need to move some markdown data from one markdown file to different  parts in my html template

I have:

1) html template
2) static build engine
3) file with markdown code

In my html template I have some `<div>` parts and
I need to combine markdown data with html template not as is. I need to cut some markdown code and put this code to different html `<div>` parts. How to do it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "cut off or move some chunks to html". Your examples show that you just want markdown to be parsed and stored as html, asis.

Comment: I need to keep my records in markdown files and I don't understand how to parse some markdown code with my html template for build static html with jekyll or middleman. For example I have code in markdown. How I can to tell to "middleman build" understand my markdown file and parse some code to "div" parts to html? How I can work with markdown code in my html template for my web-site?

Comment: have you explored using [one of these gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/markup_processors)? Especially [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)

Comment: I need to move some markdown data from one markdown file to different <div> parts in my html template

Comment: I understand how to use markdown "as is" to convert to html, but how to parse markdown to html via template to put some markdown data to different parts of html template. To different <div> around some html code. Like use erb around html.

Comment: Redcarpet has api's using which you should be able to do that.

Comment: Some examples or links may be? Thank you. I found only [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet?autoplay=true) and [af83](http://dev.af83.com/2012/02/27/howto-extend-the-redcarpet2-markdown-lib.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answering the question

As your markdown reads now it is hard to do because there is nothing in the markdown that makes it possible to extract parts of it. If you don't want to change your markdown format (or use something more suited for this) then you can do it client side with a bit of javascript (or maybe css). Put the "something else" part in the end of your generated code with an id that you find with javascript. The move it to the place where you want it. If you always have a header named Ingredients you should be able to query for that element and insert you other content before it. If you can stand wrapping you markdown *parts* with divs then it may be a bit more failsafe.

#### Better alternative

I don't know about jekyll but nanoc that I am using has a header that you put in your source file that you can extract information from in your layout. I would put title and description in there and then pull them out in my layout. The nanoc markdown file would look like this:

```
---
title: Very nice carrot soup
kind: recipe
created_at: 2013-10-03 1:59:00
author: fredrik
description: This is some really good carrot soup.....
---
### Ingredients ###

  * carrots
  * celery
  * lentils

### Cooking ###

Boil some water. And eat it with all Ingredients
```

and the layout would extract the title and the author. Snippet:

```
<div class="head">
    <h1><%= @item[:title] %></h1>
    <p><%= @item[:description] %></p>
</div>
<%= add_some_more_stuff %>
<%= yield %>
```

You can probably do something similar with jekyll.

Comment: you mean something like this?
`<div class="sidebar">
        <p><%= @item[:ingredients] %></p>
    </div>
    <%= add_some_more_stuff %>
    <div class="recepe_content">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>`

Comment: well - the yield part is giving you the main markdown as it is so if you want to have the ingredients there you don't need to add `@item[:ingredients]` to the layout also